# How to properly get text with apex in AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actually, on my website, I get some data from my database and then throw AJAX I build a table with it.

The issue is that I add to each cell a method called "Elimina()" to which I need to pass some attr got from DB it looks like something like this:

```
success: function(r) {
    data = r.d;
    data = $.parseJSON(data);
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
          var fullinizio = item.orain;
          var fullfine = item.oraout;
          $('#inizio').attr("onclick", "Elimina('" + fullinizio + ",''" + fullfine + "');");
        }
```

fullinizio and fullfine could be a string with apex inside so like "ALL'INIZIO" and that will cause a problem as the method Elimina will be interrupted as

```
"Elimina('CIAO,'ALL'INIZIO');
```

So how could I prevent that?

**UPDATE**

Just seen that by using **\'** will work fine, so how could I substitute all ' from fullinizio or fullfine to **\'**?

**UPDATE 2**

I'm creating a timeline so it's not a real table and actually that onclick is added only to a range of cells (like from 10:00PM to 12:00PM) and the real code where i use the Elimina() is the following

```
            for (i = 0; i < range; i++) {
                $(`td:eq(${inizio})`, tr).css('background-color', 'red')
                    .attr("class", codeInizio + ':' + range)
                    .attr("class", 'occupato')
                    .attr("data-inizio", fullinizio)
                    .attr("data-fine", fullfine)
                    .attr("data-id", id)
                    .attr("onclick", "Elimina('" + codeInizio + ':' + range + "','" + nome + "','" + fullinizio + "','" + fullfine + "','" + tavolo + "','" + note + "','" + coperti + "','" + tavolo + "','" + telefono + "','" + email + "','" + data + "','" + id + "');");
                inizio = inizio + 1;
            }
```

Comment: After adding my answer below, I've just realised that you're setting the attribute inside an `$.each`.  Does that mean that the data could contains multiple items, and therefore you only want the attribute to be based on the last one (because your code will overwrite the `onclick` attribute on each iteration)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding the text to the `onclick` attribute, create an `onclick` event handler instead...

That will remove any need to escape the `'` character in the two variables.

So replace...

```
$('#inizio').attr("onclick","Elimina('" + fullinizio + ",''" + fullfine + "');");
```

With...

```
$('#inizio').on("click", function() { Elimina(fullinizio,fullfine); } );
```

---

Based on the updated question, you can still use event handlers.

Note, I use the [`.off()`](https://api.jquery.com/off/) to remove existing handlers before add the new one (this is in case you run the same thing multiple times on the same set of cells)...

```
for (i = 0; i < range; i++) {
    $(`td:eq(${inizio})`, tr).css('background-color', 'red')
        .attr("class", codeInizio + ':' + range)
        ...
        .off("click")
        .on("click", function() { Elimina(codeInizio + ':' + range, nome, fullinizio, fullfine, tavolo, note, coperti, tavolo, telefono, email, data, id ); } );
    inizio = inizio + 1;
}
```

---

However, if your only option is to set the `onclick` attribute, then simply replace `'` with `\'` on each item...

```
"Elimina('" + codeInizio.replace("'","\'") + "','" + nome.replace("'","\'") + "','" + ...
```

Comment: Actually that was just an example of ajax posted in the question, it's a bit more complex as it's not a real table but a timeline so some of cell's could have the onclick and other not.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  If using an event handler is an option, then I would use it (although you have to remember that adding event handlers will continue to add, they won't replace existing one).  Otherwise, if your only option is to set the attribute, then you can simply use `fullinizio.replace("'","\'")`

Comment: Actually both options work's fine but which is better to use?

Comment: My preference is the event handler... far, far easier to read and maintain